# Suppose $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. Prove that if $g'(1)>1$, then there exists $t\in (0,1)$ with g(t) = t

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be continuously differentiable (including one-sided derivatives at 0 and 1). Suppose $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. Prove that if $g'(1)>1$, then there exists $t\in (0,1)$ with g(t) = t

Okay, this looks like a Mean Value Theorem problem, but I'm not sure how to get to proving it.

Actually, is this an Intermediate Value problem? The conclusion definitely looks like it comes from Mean Value, but the hypothesis reminds me of Intermediate Vale since the range of the function is compact. Since the range of $g$ is closed and bounded, it has a max and min, say $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ respectively. In this case, $g(a)$, the max, must be $g(1) = 1$, correct?

Now, I am not sure how $g'(1)>1$ is supposed to imply the conclusion.

Comment: "Actually, is this an Intermediate Value problem?" Yes, it is.

Comment: You should check value of $g(x) - x$ when $x$ is near to $1$ and less than $1$. You will find that there will be at least one value for which $g(x) - x < 0$. Derivative $g'(1)$ will be used for this conclusion. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(t)=g(t)-t$
Notice, that $f(0)>0$. You have to prove, that there is $t_0$ such that $f(t_0)<0$ and then just apply mean value theorem. If $f$ increases near $1$ and $f(1)=0$ then...

Comment: Is $f$ a decreasing function?

Comment: It can't be neither decreasing nor increasing since $f(0)>0$, $f(t_0)<0$ and $f(1)=0$.